# Should we rename the [federation] tag to [star-trek-federation]?

Tags: tags, discussion

Currently, the [federation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/federation) tag is for [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) questions. However, this may be slightly confusing, as there are a *lot* of 'Federation's in Scifi<sup>[*citation-needed*]</sup>.

As Rand al'Thor♦ [said in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=34634719#34634719):

> Also, should we rename it to [star-trek-federation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-federation)? There are plenty of other Federations in sci-fi.

**Should we go ahead and rename it?**

Comment: It's technically `the-united-federation-of-planets` which i believe is well-known, clear and fits in the character limit?

Comment: @CreationEdge - nope, too long.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking 30 characters, which is still only long enough if you remove "the".

Answer (score 18):

### Yes.

For the reasons mentioned.

Answer (score 12):

**This answer was based on the 25-character limit for tags, which is now invalid. I instead support [united-federation-of-planets](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11249/31178) as given in Kevin's answer.**

Not [star-trek-federation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-federation)

That was the name of an actual work that [was *going* to be developed](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Federation), and the name might eventually be used again.

It's a quibble, but I'd go with [the-federation-star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-federation-star-trek), *if* Star Trek is necessary to have in the tag name, otherwise just [the-federation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-federation).

There might be many federations throughout SFF, but *The* Federation is still generally understood as The United Federation of Planets, and a quick peek at the tag wiki excerpt should end all confusion.

It's not in our convention to stick the source universe title into the name of child tags. See: [wandlore](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wandlore) or [the-force](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-force).

We have an exception with [star-trek-data](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-data), but in my opinion that'd be better tagged as [lieutenant-commander-data](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lieutenant-commander-data) or [officer-data](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/officer-data).

Comment: We have *lots* of tags with the source universe title stuck in, especially in ST. There's [tag:star-trek-q] and [tag:star-trek-uniforms] and [tag:star-trek-emh] as well as [tag:star-trek-data].

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yeah, ST is the exception here, not really the norm. I'm really smh that some of those tags even exist, so I don't think there's any justification using them as an example of good naming conventions.

Comment: What about [ufp] or [star-trek-ufp]?  Maybe throw in a synonym?

Comment: I would say "the-force" is a poor example, given that "The Force" only exists within the Star Wars franchise. The term "federation" is much more common. I wouldn't lose much sleep over a show title that didn't even make  it past the proposal phase, let alone a script, filming, or release.

Comment: Or:  `star-trek-the-federation`.  Not anything special, but another choice.

Comment: @can-ned_food - maybe post that as an answer?

Comment: There are many federations in sci-fi but I bet there's only one "**united** federation". (What's the difference between a "federation" and a "united federation", anyway?)

Answer (score 2):

**Call it [united-federation-of-planets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-federation-of-planets)**, with synonyms [federation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/federation), [star-trek-federation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-federation), and [ufp](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ufp) (the latter for people who don't enjoy typing).  Optionally stick a `the-` in front, if you want it to sound fancy.

We ([now](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/)) have thirty-five characters to play with.  Let's be explicit.